# Retrieving Image URL from HTML code

Tags: java, html, json, jsoup

```
private String getPersonImageUrl(Document doc){
    String result = "";
    Elements wrapper = doc.getElementsByClass("article name-overview");

    return result;
}
```

Hello, I am kind of new to this information gathering from the website. I've encountered a problem I can't solve.

What I need is to retrieve the "src" image url to string "result". The "src" can be found in the link below. I've selected the class "article name-overview", because "image" can be found multiple times in the website there. What I don't know is how to proceed to retrieve the image link, located in src= value. Any help perhaps? Thank you.

P.S. Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get() in other class passed to getPersonImageUrl method. Also getting person's name is working, only struggling with picture url itself.
P.S.S. Information retrieved are for personal, non-commercial use.

[src value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeYK5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for that image, select it by its id then return its src.

```
return doc.select("#name-poster").attr("src");
```

Same approach works for other attributes like alt which appears to store a name.

```
String alt = doc.select("#name-poster").attr("alt");
String src = doc.select("#name-poster").attr("src");
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score -2):

use the .src attribute

```
return doc.getElementById("name-poster").src
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Although, when I put this in my code, it says that it cannot resolve symbol 'src'. Is there anything I am missing still?

Comment: edited from getElementsByClass to getElementById (I used the wrong property)